# Backoff usage in SimpleMessageListenerContainer class

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I can understand that `org.springframework.util.backoff` exists for simple use cases and to be used in core spring modules. (vs. using `spring-retry`).

But my question is, why `spring-amqp` uses it instead of `spring-retry` in `handleStartupFailure()` of `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` as `spring-retry` is already a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally, the listener container had no mechanism to backoff, just a `recoveryInterval`.

When backoff was added, we didn't need the extra capabilities provided by spring-retry (exception classification, stateful retry, etc) so it seemed simpler to use the Spring utility.

What is your concern? What is not provided by the current mechanism that you need?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought there's another reason, perhaps something I need to understand.